# How to interpret a sub-band structure of a nano-ribbon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

The way I understand a band structure diagram is that it basically tells us at a given point in space ($k_x,k_y,k_z$) what is the allowed energy value(s).

A usual band structure of 2D graphene is given below:

[image]

This diagram is what I can interpret as: at a given value of $k_x, k_y$ there is some allowed energy value.

Now, have a look at the band structure of zigzag graphene nanoribbon:

[image]

Here $N$ is the width of a nanoribbon. I have two questions here:

1. Why there are discrete lines in energy spectrum now?
2. How this spectrum is helpful to analyze topological surface states? How can we tell if the system is topological or not?

Comment: In the discrete lines each corresponds to different $k_\perp$ mode, see [this animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cnt_zz_v3.gif) from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene_nanoribbons). You can view them as slices in your $k_x$-$k_y$ diagram for the bulk graphene.